# How to use the Landscape API in Landscape On-Premises correctly?

Tags: server, landscape

I am running Landscape On-Premises (version 16.06) on Ubuntu Server 16.04. When I connect to the server via the web interface, everything is working as expected. Additionally I installed and configured the landscape-api package to manage the server via ssh. When I use landscape-api as described in the [Landscape API documentation](https://landscape.canonical.com/static/doc/api/), nothing usable returns from given commands :

```
source /home/cl/landscape-api.rc

landscape-api get-activities
No JSON object could be decoded

landscape-api get-computers
No JSON object could be decoded

landscape-api get-event-log
No JSON object could be decoded

landscape-api --json get-activities
Query API Service

landscape-api --json get-computers
Query API Service

landscape-api --json get-event-log
Query API Service
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rc file you sourced is probably incorrect, or the api service isn't running. Did you copy and paste from what landscape offered you in your user settings page?

Check the process listing on the landscape server and look for the api process. Also check the server logs in `/var/log/landscape-server/`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Andreas ! :) The .rc file being sourced contains the credentials created and offered in the user settings tab. Doing this manually executing the command : landscape-api --key <my-access-key> --secret <my-secret-key> --uri https://<my-endpoint-server-url>/api/) <command> doesn't make any difference. I also checked landscape-api service (systemctl status landscape-api), it is running, although it is not listed as a running process (ps -A). A clean new installation of the whole landscape environment on basic server setup brought no changes or improvements. :)

Comment: If accessing https://<server>/api shows you "Query API Service", then the service is running and fine. What could be wrong now is something in the way between your api client and the server, like a proxy, or a slightly incorrect URL, like with or without an ending slash ("/").

Comment: I do not use a proxy, but I have to take http : http://<my-endpoint-server-url>/api/ instead of https://<my-endpoint-server-url>/api/ to access the api, otherwise I receive an error message. But your answer led me to the solution ... finally ! My host names contained upper-case letters, after changing them to lower-case letters only and executing landscape-api with lower-case letters exclusively, it works ! Thank you again ! :)