# Landscape - update_security_db.sh: connection to the other side was refused

Tags: 16.04, landscape

Question at [landscape alert - script with issues : update_security_db.sh](https://askubuntu.com/questions/818983/landscape-alert-script-with-issues-update-security-db-sh) may seem similar however the issue is different, the error message here says connection was refused that issue says connection was lost.

Landscape's update_security_db.sh does not seem to be running correctly.  The following is output on attempting to run the script manually;

```
<11>Oct  4 19:18:16 update-security-db: Traceback (most recent call last):
<11>Oct  4 19:18:16 update-security-db:   File "./process-usns", line 7, in <module>
<11>Oct  4 19:18:16 update-security-db:     canonical.landscape.scripts.usn.run()
<11>Oct  4 19:18:16 update-security-db:   File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/scripts/batch.py", line 64, in __call__
<11>Oct  4 19:18:16 update-security-db:     self.setup()
<11>Oct  4 19:18:16 update-security-db:   File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/scripts/batch.py", line 105, in setup
<11>Oct  4 19:18:16 update-security-db:     self._stop_amqp_client = run_amqp_client_in_thread(config)
<11>Oct  4 19:18:16 update-security-db:   File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/setup.py", line 336, in run_amqp_client_in_thread
<11>Oct  4 19:18:16 update-security-db:     blockingCallFromThread(reactor, lambda: started)
<11>Oct  4 19:18:16 update-security-db:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/threads.py", line 122, in blockingCallFromThread
<11>Oct  4 19:18:16 update-security-db:     result.raiseException()
<11>Oct  4 19:18:16 update-security-db:   File "<string>", line 2, in raiseException
<11>Oct  4 19:18:16 update-security-db: twisted.internet.error.ConnectionRefusedError: Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused.
```

The same error is displayed in Landscape's server logs.  I'm really not sure what I causing this.

Comment: anything of interest in the log in `/var/log/landscape-server/update-security-db.log` ?

Comment: Don't think so, file is filled with http://hastebin.com/edawecenig.sql

Comment: Possibly related: http://serverfault.com/questions/708909/ssh-connection-refused-error-message

Comment: It would seem that either the credentials aren't being accepted or it's some sort of overload condition on the receiving end.

Comment: Check if `rabbitmq` is running, if it's not check the logs in `/var/log/rabbitmq `. Most frequent problem with rabbit is that it can't resolve the hostname of the machine, so make sure you have `/etc/hosts` or DNS set up

Comment: Thanks, rabbitmq doesn't appear to be running, the rabbit@xxx.log file; http://hastebin.com/pubamubewe.sql, rabbit@xxx-sasl.log; http://hastebin.com/ifofovokem.sql

Comment: Any ideas @AdamCollard or @ElderGeek?

Answer (score 0):

I had same situation. I used landscape-server on a server with a host name which contains upper-case letters, and I changed the upper-case letters to lower-case  letters in host name. And then, I purged `landscape-server-quickstart` and reinstalled it. That solved the situation.

```
sudo apt purge landscape-server-quickstart
sudo apt purge rabbitmq-server               # remove rabbitmq settings too.
sudo apt autoremove 
sudo apt install landscape-server-quickstart
```

[landscape alert - script with issues : update_security_db.sh](https://askubuntu.com/questions/818983/landscape-alert-script-with-issues-update-security-db-sh)

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the rabbitmq is okay, because when it is down you get the 111 error as well when it attempts to process the downloaded file.

I had this same situation when rabbitmq was not running correctly and `rabbitmqctl status` was showing

```
Status of node rabbit@landscape
Error: unable to connect to node rabbit@landscape: nodedown

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: [rabbit@landscape]

rabbit@landscape:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on landscape
  * epmd reports: node 'rabbit' not running at all
                  other nodes on landscape: ['rabbitmq-cli-55']
  * suggestion: start the node
```

But the command `rabbitmqctl start_app` was not starting it and giving an error:

```
Starting node rabbit@landscape
Error: unable to connect to node rabbit@landscape: nodedown
```

I found a report in a forum where clearing rabbitmq logs worked. I tried the following:

```
sudo service rabbitmq-server stop
sudo rm -rf /var/log/rabbitmq/*
sudo service rabbitmq-server start
```

After this I could `rabbitmqctl start_app` and the node came up. 
Manually calling the update_security_db script with `sudo -u landscape bash -x /opt/canonical/landscape/scripts/update_security_db.sh` now worked